# Angular NG5002: @for loop must have a "track" expression

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular 17 introduced a new control flow syntax moving from

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items"></div>
```

to

```js
@for (item of items) {
    <div></div>
}
```

When directly translating my loops, I get the following error:

```
 NG5002: @for loop must have a "track" expression
```

Comment: Feature, not a bug

Comment: @AndrewAllen Yes a very cool feature as well. Still something many might not be aware of when migrating. So I deemed it helpful to post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Background

As part of the new control flow structure introduced in [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) v17 the `track` expression needs to be defined.

Track is used to keep track of items in an array and their association to the DOM.

From the Angular documentation:

> The value of the `track` expression determines a key used to associate array items with the views in the DOM. Having clear indication of the item identity allows Angular to execute a minimal set of DOM operations as items are added, removed or moved in a collection.

> Loops over immutable data without `trackBy` as one of the most common causes for performance issues across Angular applications. Because of the potential for poor performance, the `track` expression is required for the `@for` loops. When in doubt, using `track $index` is a good default.

From :https://angular.dev/guide/templates/control-flow#track-for-calculating-difference-of-two-collections

## Solutions

### Use a property of the element

If the elements in your array have any kind of property attached to them that allows identifying them you can use it for the tracking. Any kind of ID works great.

```js
let items = [
    { id: "id1", content: []},
    { id: "id2", content: []},
]
```

```js
@for (item of items; track item.id) {
    <div></div>
}
```

### Use `track $index`

This uses the index of the current row to associate the row with the element in the DOM. This can be used as default, if no better property is available and the array itself is immutable.

```js
@for (item of items; track $index) {
    <div></div>
}
```

`$index` will be recalculated if an item is added to the array, so it could lead to some unexpected behaviour or performance issues, and should not be used if a unique identifier is available.

Comment: Can you use more than one tracking variable? for example: `track item.id; track item.order`?

Comment: Track is used internally by angular to ensure that it still knows which item is which, when a change happens.
You can still access the item itself and all its properties. 
If the id by itself is not unique, you could create a compound id by combining it. E.g. `track item.id + item.order`

Comment: so chaining of multiple properties is OK to track by? and the syntax is with a `+` sign? Also, much obliged for the explanation!